# Java 9 Maven module not found in console

Tags: java, maven, java-platform-module-system

I am building a Jigsaw module using Maven.Here is a simple class inside of it

```
public class Welcome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Java 9 Modular Welcome");

        Module module =  Welcome.class.getModule();
        System.out.printf("Module name: %s%n",module.getName());
    }
}
```

module-info.java

```
module org.abondar.experimental.intro {

exports  org.abondar.experimental.intro;
}
```

Maven compiler plugin set up

```
 <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jdkToolchain>
                        <version>[1.8,9)</version>
                    </jdkToolchain>
                    <source>9</source>
                    <target>9</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
```

And Jar plugin

```
  <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/org.abondar.experimental.intro</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>org.abondar.experimental.intro.Welcome</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>./lib</Class-Path>
                            <Module-Path>./mods</Module-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

So in IDE this code works as expected. But in console getModule returns null. I believe I have misconfigured one of Maven plugins because in console module is not in module path. So what exactly is wr

Comment: What command do you use to run this via console? And if you could actually look into the IDE logs and check what command is executed by it?

Comment: Don't use `<sourceDirectory>src/main/org.abondar.experimental.intro</sourceDirectory>`..Just keep the conventions and put the source code into `src/main/java`...and put the `module-info.java` into `src/main/java`..

Comment: @nullpointer I used java -jar which wasn't correct

Comment: @khmarbaise is there any convention about maven usage with jigsaw? I saw that for jigsaw source folder named as I did though some people do as you suggest. I will stick for now with the style I have shown here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after sometime and careful reading I understood my mistake: I didn't run jar correctly.

So here how should it be:

```
java --module-path target/Intro-1.0.jar -m org.abondar.experimental.intro/org.abondar.experimental.intro.Welcome
```

Instead of just running

```
java -jar target/Intro-1.0.jar
```

Comment: If the mainclass is defined in  the MANIFEST. There is no other reason I see currently why `java -jar ...` shouldn't work. Other than the poor folder naming already pointed out by khmarbaise. Could you explain why `java -jar` didn't work.

Comment: From the book "Java 9 Revealed for Early Adoption and Migration": The -jar option existed before
JDK 9. In JDK 9, a type can be loaded as part of a module via a module path or via a class path. If a type is
loaded via a class path, the type becomes a member of a module called an unnamed module. The type loses
its membership from its original module, even though the type is loaded from a modular JAR. In fact, if a
modular JAR is placed on the class path, it is treated as a JAR (not a modular JAR), ignoring its module-info.
class file."